# Django UnicodeDecodeError в продакшн режиме

Tags: python-3.x, django

Есть проект на `django` и в нем ошибка над которой я уже второй день голову ломаю. Локально, что в дев, что в прод режиме, все работает превосходно, но когда заливаю на сервер (beget.ru если это важно), выскакивает `UnicodeDecodeError` на русские буквы в темплейтах.

Comment: Без хотя бы полного traceback мы вам ничем помочь не сможем

Comment: А вообще вы проверяли, что на сервере используется та же версия питона, что и у вас локально?